# pandas.DataFrame.replace is not working when I tried to replace '+' from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I am trying to replace the character '+' with nothing using `pandas.DataFrame.replace`.

It works sometimes but sometimes it doesn't replace.

I am using jupyter notebook.

Code:

```
df_raw['Installs'] = df_raw.Installs.replace('+', '')
```

Output:

```
10000+
500000+
5000000+
50000000+
100000+
```

Comment: `df_raw.Installs.replace('+', '', regex=True)`

Comment: you need use `str.replace()` each time... df_raw.Installs.str.replace(',','').str.replace('+','')

Comment: Why the code is ```replace(',', '')``` when you want to replace ```'+'```? Also, please clarify whether you want to replace only trailing ```'+'``` or all occurences, in the designated column(s) or the whole dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the [str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) method.

```
df_raw['Installs'] = df_raw.Installs.str.replace('+', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data.column.apply(lambda x:x.replace("+",""))
```

```
# make it int
data.column.apply(lambda x:x.replace("+","")).astype(int)
```

this should work